# Back4App Parse on iOS - how to send Push notifications from client side in reworked ParseSwift SDK 2.0?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification, back4app

I am a hobby Android programmer and have been taking my first steps with Swift by porting an existing Android app to iOS. My Android app relies on Parse as the backend and I am struggling with one specific function of my Back4App backend implementation:

I am trying to send channel-based push notifications from the client side, which is easily possible in Android by subscribing to a channel and sending a push notification to said channel. This push notification can be triggered from the client side.
The tutorials on the Back4App website describe the necessary steps with the ParseSDK 1.8.1., whose Swift syntax is very similar to the Android implementation.

Unfortunately, the ParseSDK has been reworked heavily in its current version 2.3.1 to be more Swift-specific. I read the official documentation and googled left and right, but using channels is seemingly not possible in ParseSDK 2.3.1. (or simply not implemented yet?)

Does anyone know how to use channel-based push notification subscriptions with ParseSDK 2.3.1? Or is there a way to use the older version of the ParseSDK for the Push Notifications only?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not secure to send push notification from the client and that's why the new ParseSwift SDK does not even have this feature. You will have to create a cloud code function for that and the client can call the cloud code function instead of sending the push notification directly.

Comment: Hey Davi, thanks for your comment and input! Good to know that this feature was scrapped altogether, I will look into CloudCode then and also retrofit the Android app.